# No empty lines after converting docx

Tags: java, freemarker, xdocreport

I have docx file with many empty lines for visual separating blocks. But after converting my docx to HTML of pdf, the blank lines are miss. Is there any possibility to configure this behaviour? I convert using xwfp with freemarker engine. Xdoc version `2.0.1`

Tried to switch to version `2.0.2` and tried to use `docx4j` converter - docx4j makes doc very ugly.

Comment: I have the same problem, but editing the document in Microsoft Word. Do you add empty lines only with `Enter`? Did you use also table in your documents?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I edited document in open office, not in microsoft office.